# Welch Pairwise Comparisons in SAS

Tags: r, statistics, sas

Does anyone know how to go about doing finding Welch pairwise comparisons in SAS? I know I can do comparisons a single t-test at a time, unfortunately there are 12 treatment combinations, so that would mean 60+ pairwise comparisons.

I need to use Welch t-tests because my data is heterogeneous, and there were no reasonable response variable transformations.

Thanks you for the help.

(I am open to R programming suggestions as well, but I am very much a rookie when it comes to R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this syntax](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_ttest_syntax05.htm) would help make your combinations more manageable?